# Why doesn't this makefile pattern rule match?

Tags: makefile

I have the following structure in my project

```
project 
 /<source-files>
 /obj
   / <obj-files>
```

I have following receipe in my Makefile

```
ALL_OBJ := obj/malloc.o obj/ll.o obj/llist.o obj/socket.o obj/util.o obj/event.o

...

obj/%.o : ./%.c ./%.h
    $(GCC) -g -c -o $@  $< -lpthread $(ALL_INC) $(CFLAGS) ${ADD_CLFAGS}

...

libshmsock.a : $(ALL_OBJ)
    ar rcs libshmsock.a $^
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/llist.o', needed by 'libshmsock.a'.  Stop.
```

Why doesnt the pattern rule `obj/%.o` match `obj/llist.o`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it while i wrote the question, but I thought maybe it helps someone. The Problem was that I didn't have llist.c in my sources directory. I still find the error a bit weird though. I mean: Why doesn't makefile report an error like `make: *** No rule to make target 'llist.c', needed by 'obj/llist.o'.  Stop.`? Would have saved me some hours

Comment: `make` does not report an error such as you would have liked because `make` can't recognize that you want your pattern rule to apply to building `obj/llist.o` when `./llist.c` or `./llist.h` doesn't actually exist.  `make` has a bunch of built-in implicit rules that also could have been used to build `obj/llist.o` if the appropriate prerequisite(s) were present.  Should `make` report diagnostics related to each of them?

Comment: As John says, make has 13 different pattern rules for building `%.o` files, plus your rules.  Also, there are numerous pattern rules that would allow make to create a missing `%.c` file, that make needs to check.  You happen to know exactly what's missing so you can suggest the specific message that would help you, but of course make can't know which one of all those things are the actual problem so it would just have to report all of them.

Comment: Also, at the time make is looking for patterns it doesn't know that it won't find one, so it would have to remember all the things it tried so that if, later on, it decided nothing worked it could print them all out.  If you want a hint of the things make is checking and how many output messages you would get, try running `make -d` and see what it says... I'm not convinced that receiving that wall of output scrolling up your screen would be an improvement in understanding or finding the issue.

Comment: If you don't want to debug these kinds of errors, something you can do is stop using pattern rules.  If you use explicit rules instead, then make knows _exactly_ what should be there and will fail with a specific error if it isn't there.  You can use static pattern rules (which are, confusing, actually explicit rules not implicit rules) to still use explicit rules without writing out N rules for N targets.